# Running WSO2 API Manager on Heroku

Tags: heroku, wso2

Is there a straightforward way to run WSO2 API Manager on Heroku? I've been through the basic Heroku docs on how to deploy Java applications and understand that process but it seems like jumping through hoops that maybe aren't needed.

I'd like to be able to simply upload the installed application (binary version of application) and a procfile that defines the bootstrap class file as the starting point.

Is this possible? Is there another way to get Java apps to run in Heroku without defining a pom.xml and having it build the application prior to deployment?

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 4):

WSO2 offers the hybrid API model to deploy your WSO2 API gateway on Heroku and use WSO2 API Cloud to manage your APIs.

You can use WSO2 [WSO2 Heroku Add-on](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/wso2apicloud) which can be used as WSO2 API publisher and Store. Then use [Heroku Button](https://elements.heroku.com/buttons/wso2/cloud-heroku-api-gateway) to deploy WSO2 API Gateway on Heroku.

More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/wso2apicloud

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is no straightforward way to run WSO2 API Manager on Heroku. I looked at [how Java programs are run on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java) and it seems your requirement cannot be achieved currently. Heroku seems to be depending on Maven projects.

WSO2 API Manager product is built from WSO2 Carbon platform, which is not a simple Maven Java project.

Heroku also runs the Java application on OpenJDK, which is not supported by WSO2 API Manager. Only Oracle JDK is supported as mentioned in [Installation Prerequisites](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM140/Installation+Prerequisites).

I hope this helps.